# Cannot update dialog control on button click

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-mobile

So I have this dialog CTestPrintDlg that has an edit control IDC_AVAILABLE_BALANCE and a button WithdrawVoucher.

Inside CTestPrintDlg::OnBnClickedButtonWithdrawVoucher() I do some stuff that works fine, and at the end I'm trying to update the edit control text.

Inside the handler for button click have tried the following:

```
this->GetDlgItem(IDC_AVAILABLE_BALANCE)->SetWindowTextW(_T("blah"));
```

and

```
CTestPrintDlg::GetDlgItem(IDC_AVAILABLE_BALANCE)->SetWindowTextW(_T("blah"));
```

have also tried this (after defining the control variable)

```
CTestPrintDlg::Main_window_balance_control.SetWindowTextW(_T("blah"));
```

and also (after defining the value variable)

```
CTestPrintDlg::Main_window_balance_var = _T("blah");
```

and also

```
CTestPrintDlg::Main_window_balance_var.SetString(_T("blah"));
```

and have also tried at the end

```
CTestPrintDlg::UpdateData(TRUE);
```

All with no luck. Does anyone have a clue why this won't work?

**Update**:

Curiously, if I do this:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_AVAILABLE_BALANCE)->SetWindowTextW(_T("blah"));
```

Control text is deleted.

Comment: And what do you do after attempting to set the edit control text? If you don't return from the button handler function the edit control won't get a chance to repaint itself.

Comment: Tired returning some random value, still no luck :(

Comment: If the program is still alive after setting the text, it seems likely you have the wrong ID for the edit control.

Comment: Nope, the ID is fine. Triple checked that 5 times so far. Really strange stuff.

Comment: Another strange thing is that I am able to set the text for that control from within CTestPrintDlg::OnInitDialog()

Comment: By any chance are you setting the text from a secondary thread? That brings in a lot of complications.

Comment: No, same thread. And I can update all other edit controls just not this one for some reason.

Comment: If you can modify the text in the other edit controls on the same dialog, but not this one, then there must be something different about this edit control. Check the window styles and attributes. Look at how this control is created - is it in any way different from the others on that dialog? Is the parent control for this edit control the same as for the other edit controls that do work?

Comment: Did that already, even deleted the control several times and re-added it. Not sure what's going on really.

Comment: Take a look at your .rc file. Make sure you can account for all of the controls in there. Maybe you have two overlayed on top of each other. Also look at your resources.h file and make sure all of the controls have different ID numbers.

Comment: There was nothing overlayed, the IDs were fine. I just removed that feature at least for the time being. I think it may have something to do with the content loading via CInternetSession but I also have other stuff loading just fine into some other fields, button labels and so on.